# Ajax call inside for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

How to properly show and hide ajax loader along with ajax call in for loop.

```
$scope.upload = function(){
    $(".loader").show();
     for(var i=0;i<count ;i++){
     $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/upload",
               data: data;
               contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
               success: function(msg){

                 }); 
               }
             });
}
```

}

Comment: Make a varibale flagCounter and  increment the counterFlag  after a ajax request complete, and check if the count is equal no of requests if yes then hide the loader

Answer (score 1):

One option is to check when all ajax call has been done:

```
$scope.upload = function(){
    $(".loader").show();
    var calls = [];
     for(var i=0;i<count ;i++){
     calls[i] = $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/upload",
                   data: data;
                   contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
                   success: function(msg){

                   }); 

             });
    }
    Promisse.all(calls).then(function(data){
        $(".loader").hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you. This post just solved my 2 days old problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
$(".loader").show();
var counterFlag =0;
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    $.ajax({
            //ajax options
            success: function(msg){

            },
            complete:function(d){
                counterFlag++;
                if(counterFlag==count)
                {
                    $(".loader").hide();
                }
            });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Loader not hiding ?

Comment: hiding but...my loader image having  spining motion ..circular rotation ,which is   stucking

Comment: Check your GIF image that you are using in loader. It's not a problem of js code